# "All I got was this lousy t-shirt"-type slogan in Italian?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

My partner has gone back to Italy to visit family for christmas - I'm flying out in a few days, and she asked me to buy for her sister a t-shirt that says "My sister goes to [university/city name] and all I got was this lousy t-shirt". I couldn't find one in the shops so I thought I'd make one.

I was thinking maybe I'd write it in English on the front and Italian on the back. My Italian è molto male, and I could ask my partner but that would ruin the surprise. So I was wondering whether someone could advise me on whether there is a usual phrasing for this kind of t-shirt joke in Italy, or if not, of a good way to translate it. Off the top of my head, I think the best thing I could come up with on my own would be something like

> Mia sorella studia in [place], e io ho solo questa maglietta male!

Comment: It's best you to tell us what is the name of the University as in Italian it's somehow hard to coordinate the proposition to its noun: *Mia sorella studia a Yale...*, or *...studia al MIT...*, or else *...studia all'UCLA...*.

Comment: @N74: Right, but not so hard. In general, if the university is defined by its *location*, we tend to omit the article (*studia a Oxford, a Princeton, a Pisa...*), while if we use the *name* of an institution, we tend to use the article (*studia al MIT, all'UCLA, al Queen Mary, alla Sorbona, alla Normale...*). In this context, Yale and Harvard are often misused in Italian, perhaps because some people think they are names of places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slight variation on Josh61's answer: “*Mia sorella studia a ... e non mi ha portato altro che questo schifo di maglietta*”, or with “*mi ha portato solo*” in the place of “*non mi ha portato altro che*”.

Answer (score 7):

This is a translation you might use:

> - Mia sorella studia all'università di ...e tutto quello che mi ha portato è questa schifosissima maglietta.

Comment: Inoltre, *schifosissima* si può sostituire con parecchi aggettivi, come *orribile*, *stupida*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

An expression that matches the spirit I perceive from the English slogan is *Mia sorella studia a... e tutto quello che ci ho guadagnato è questa stupida maglietta*.

I would use *ci ho guadagnato* because I think the joke relies strictly on the idea that someone is doing something supposedly important, "high-flying" (even just sarcastically, and not necessarily traveling or residing in some away place) and someone else connected to this person is expecting to obtain from that some advantage for himself / herself (which also carries a sarcastic value, and also not limited to receiving a souvenir from the place where the first person traveled / resided).

I used *stupid* because I think it's important that the joke points to the T-shirt being something simply useless or of little value because it's just a T-shirt, regardless of whether it's ugly or beautiful as a T-shirt.

In any case mind @N74's comment about the proposition, it might cause errors.

Comment: I see @SantiBailors's point, but I find *ottenuto* slightly stilted here. In the sense he points out, I'd go for *tutto quello che ne ho ricavato* or *tutto quello che ci ho guadagnato*.

Comment: @DaG I agree. Of your two options I like _ci ho guadagnato_ better, because I think that to match the original joke (this specific one) it's important to keep the tone on as colloquial a level as possible, and _ci ho guadagnato_ does the job perfectly.